# How to make irb exit on CTRL + C

Tags: ruby

By default ruby's irb doesn't exit when `CTRL+C` pressed.

Is there a way to alter it so it would exit? Maybe require some script `irb -r some_script.rb` that would make it exit when `CTRL+C` pressed?

Comment: Assume that this is possible, without hacking the irb source code (perhaps it is): How would you then abort an infinite loop in irb? What is so bad in exiting irb with CTRL+D?

Comment: Hmmmm.... Mine does. Which operating system and Ruby implementation are you using? I run Ruby 2.6.4 for Cygwin, on Windows, but if I remember right, the irb on Linux and MacOS also reacted on Control-D. Does your shell inside the terminal react on Control-D?

Comment: @user1934428 sorry, I made mistake in previous comment I meant 'CTRL+C', I usually press 'CTRL+C' to terminate any running program in terminal, and it seems like it's works. The only exception is IRB that doesn't exit on this command

Comment: Control-C sends a signal to the program, which is handled as the command decides to handle it. The default is a graceful shutdown. Many interactive programs handle it as _terminating the current calculation_. irb is doing this for instance. OTOH, Control-D does not send a signal, but just a Control-D-Character. It is a convention that if the **first** character in an input line is a control-D, this is interpreted as "end of input", which means that the program terminates. Your shell is supposed to do it in this way, and irb too.  Try it, but make sure that you type it at the start of the line.

Comment: If irb is doing a calculation at the time you want to terminate it, first do a Control-C to get back to the irb prompt, and then a Control-D to end the program.

Comment: It's not just IRB, this is how many [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)s / shells work. ^C interrupts the current command (e.g. a loop, a long-running method, or a `gets` call) whereas ^D terminates your interactive session. You might know this from SSH or even Bash itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I had to see it in the source code after making a hack solution and accidentally stumbling on this:
*https://github.com/ruby/irb/blob/v1.6.3/lib/irb/context.rb#L239-L247*

```rb
# Whether <code>^C</code> (+control-c+) will be ignored or not.
#
# If set to +false+, <code>^C</code> will quit irb.
#
# If set to +true+,
#
# * during input:   cancel input then return to top level.
# * during execute: abandon current execution.
attr_accessor :ignore_sigint
```

Which you set like this:

```rb
# .irbrc

IRB.conf[:IGNORE_SIGINT] = false
```

---

<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> are pretty standard and used  everywhere. In ruby, `trap` method is how you catch signals, in case you need it for something else:

```rb
>> trap("INT") { puts "see ya"; exit }
>> # Ctrl-C
see ya
$
```